# get GridView Item exactly square

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-listview

I am using a grid view to show my data [i.e. A image and its tiltle]

And my image is loaded dynamically with my imageloader library. The issue is some of my images are in landscape or portrait. And due to this my grid element dont maintain exact square ratio. Some are vertically stretch or compressed other wise.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/fcpl_grid_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollingCache="false"/>
```

Here is my getView method:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder viewholder;
            Log.e("Calling...","getView");
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_product_list, parent, false);
                viewholder = new ViewHolder();
                viewholder.productImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ipl_imageview);
                viewholder.backGroundLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ipl_bk_layout);
                viewholder.productName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ipl_productname);
                convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            } else {
                viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewholder.productName.setText("SOME TEXT");
            String imageUrl = "SOME URL";
            imageLoader.get(imageUrl, VALUES_FOR_MY_IMAGE_LOADER_LIBRARY));
            return convertView;
        }
```

I tried different suggested method online but none work as i have dynamic image loading and the imageView layoutParams are not known when the getView is called.

Comment: Why don't you fix the height and width of your `ImageView` ?

Comment: NO i cant; I have to Keep the GridView width as Fill parent; and there are 2 columns in the grid view. So i dont know the exact height [i.e. Height = Width]

Comment: You have to just fixed Height of image.

Comment: Height should be exactly same as the width [and width is dynamic, will be different for different screen]

Comment: @AabidMulani Then make the `ImageView` `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to make class that extends `ImageView` (or `GridView`) and measure bounds of root or any other parent view. Then just use it in your item xml.

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        View rootView = this.getRootView();
        if (rootView != null) {
            width = rootView.getWidth();
            height = rootView.getHeight();
        }
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        super.onMeasure(size, size);
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
}
```